# Sharing common projects with Maven

Tags: maven, eclipse-rcp, tycho, e4

I'm coping with the problem of restructuring our Maven build processes to share common projects among all all our projects, but I can't get it working.

So far we have five GUIs (RCP E4 with JavaFX) which use in total thirty libs. Those are partially ours (source code) and 3rd party (jars). Every GUI has its own (working) Maven build process. Every GUI has its own Git with a copy of every lib needed for compilation. To give you an idea how the dependencies look like (only a few GUIs and a few common libs):

[image]

Now I want to get rid of the redundancy in these projects. As I said every GUI has its own Git and its own copy(!) of the required common project. I already created Gits for the common libraries to separate them. Now comes my problem. Until now every of these common projects had its own `pom.xml` in which I need to specify a parent. Here is an example `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>gui.a.e4</groupId>
        <artifactId>gui.a.e4.app.releng</artifactId>
        <relativePath>../gui.a.e4.app.releng/pom.xml</relativePath>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
  <groupId>gui.a.e4</groupId>
  <artifactId>common.project.x</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>
</project>
```

At first I tried to just include `common.project.x` into `gui.b.e4` which resulted in the following error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not resolve target platform specification artifact gui.a:gui.a.app.target:target:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not resolve target platform specification artifact gui.a:gui.a.app.target:target:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:168)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not resolve target platform specification artifact gui.a:gui.a.app.target:target:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.resolver.DefaultTargetPlatformConfigurationReader.addTargetArtifact(DefaultTargetPlatformConfigurationReader.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.resolver.DefaultTargetPlatformConfigurationReader.setTarget(DefaultTargetPlatformConfigurationReader.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.resolver.DefaultTargetPlatformConfigurationReader.getTargetPlatformConfiguration(DefaultTargetPlatformConfigurationReader.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.resolver.DefaultTychoResolver.setupProject(DefaultTychoResolver.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.maven.TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.afterProjectsRead(TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.java:90)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:274)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    ... 11 more
[ERROR]
```

This error results from the fact, that Maven tries to find the parent of `common.project.x` and tries to resolve it and the parent's parent which in this case needs to create the target platform (some RCP E4 specific thing). My first attempt to solve this problem was to remove the parent from the `pom.xml`. So when I don't specify the parent in `common.project.x` the build of `gui.a.e4` complains that:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project auv.e4:art.util.geo:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT (/home/mhoffmann/apps/workspace_rcp_gui/art.util.geo.bundle/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Unknown packaging: eclipse-plugin @ line 8, column 14
[ERROR]
```

and if I afterwards change the packaging type to `pom` other projects can't find this project:

```
[ERROR] Cannot resolve project dependencies:
[ERROR]   Software being installed: gui.a.e4.application 1.0.0.qualifier
[ERROR]   Missing requirement: common.project.y 1.0.0.qualifier requires 'bundle common.project.x 0.0.0' but it could not be found
[ERROR]   Cannot satisfy dependency: gui.a.e4.application 1.0.0.qualifier depends on: bundle common.project.y 0.0.0
[ERROR]
```

Here is the maven XML for building one of our GUI's, they are all equal (except for names of the projects)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <name>gui.a - releng</name>
        <prerequisites>
                <maven>3.0</maven>
        </prerequisites>
        <groupId>gui.a</groupId>
        <artifactId>gui.a.app.releng</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>pom</packaging>
        <properties>
                <tycho-version>0.23.1</tycho-version>
                <junit-version>4.11</junit-version>
                <mockito-version>1.8.4</mockito-version>
                <platform-version>4.2</platform-version>
                <efx-version>1.0.0</efx-version>
                <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
                <show-eclipse-log>true</show-eclipse-log>
        </properties>
        <modules>
                <module>../gui.a.app</module>
                <module>../gui.a.app.feature</module>
                <module>../gui.a.app.product</module>
                <module>../gui.a.specific.project.a</module>
                <module>../gui.a.specific.project.b</module>
                <module>../common.project.a</module>
                <module>../common.project.b</module>
        </modules>
                <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                        <id>tycho</id>
                        <url>http://repository.sonatype.org/content/groups/sonatype-public-grid</url>
                        <snapshots>
                                <enabled>true</enabled>
                        </snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
        <build>
                <!-- build plugins -->
                <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                                <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                                <extensions>true</extensions>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                                <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
                                <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                                <configuration>
                                        <target>
                                                <artifact>
                                                        <groupId>gui.a</groupId>
                                                        <artifactId>gui.a.app.target</artifactId>
                                                        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                                                </artifact>
                                        </target>
                                        <resolver>p2</resolver>

                                        <pomDependencies>consider</pomDependencies>
                                        <environments>
                                                <environment>
                                                        <os>win32</os>
                                                        <ws>win32</ws>
                                                        <arch>x86</arch>
                                                </environment>
                                                <environment>
                                                        <os>win32</os>
                                                        <ws>win32</ws>
                                                        <arch>x86_64</arch>
                                                </environment>
                                                <environment>
                                                        <os>linux</os>
                                                        <ws>gtk</ws>
                                                        <arch>x86_64</arch>
                                                </environment>
                                                <environment>
                                                    <os>macosx</os>
                                                    <ws>cocoa</ws>
                                                    <arch>x86_64</arch>
                                            </environment>
                                        </environments>
                                </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                </plugins>
                <!-- defines the default settings for the used plugins -->
                <pluginManagement>
                        <plugins>
                                <plugin>
                                        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>tycho-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                                        <configuration>
                                                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                                                <source>1.8</source>
                                                <target>1.8</target>
                                                <extraClasspathElements>
                                                        <extraClasspathElement>
                                                                <groupId>javafx</groupId>
                                                                <artifactId>javafx.mvn</artifactId>
                                                                <version>2.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                                                        </extraClasspathElement>
                                                </extraClasspathElements>
                                        </configuration>
                                </plugin>
                                <plugin>
                                        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>tycho-source-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                                        <executions>
                                                <execution>
                                                        <id>plugin-source</id>
                                                        <goals>
                                                                <goal>plugin-source</goal>
                                                        </goals>
                                                </execution>
                                        </executions>
                                </plugin>
                                <plugin>
                                        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>tycho-packaging-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                                        <configuration>
                                                <archive>
                                                        <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                                                </archive>
                                        </configuration>
                                </plugin>
                        </plugins>
                </pluginManagement>
        </build>
        <dependencyManagement>
                <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                                <version>${junit-version}</version>
                                <scope>test</scope>
                        </dependency>
                </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
                        <version>${mockito-version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>junit</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                        <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
        </dependencies>
</project>
```

I also don't know how the POMs of the common projects should look like or what to do. I don't have much knowledge about Maven, it is only sufficient for adapting existing scripts to include more `common.project`s :-). So far I don't know what I should change in order to make it working. Help me please, Maven drives me crazy. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arrows in your graph indicate a hierarchical structure (with the topmost level at the bottom of your chart). Considering this declaring a `common.project.x` as a sub-module (`<module>../common.project.a</module>`) of a GUI is counter-intuitive. Especially if two GUIs are referencing the same `common.project.x`.

I'd suggest the following structure:

```
+ main
  +- pom.xml  ... declarations common to all projects, common and gui as sub-modules
  +- common
     +- pom.xml  ... declarations common to common.projects, common.projects as sub-modules
     +- common.project.a
        +- pom.xml
     +- common.project.b
        +- pom.xml  ... including direct dependency to a
     +- ...
        +- ... 
  +- gui
     +- pom.xml  ... declarations common to GUI projects, GUI projects as sub-modules
     +- GUI a
        +- pom.xml  ... including direct dependencies to b, c
     +- GUI b
        +- pom.xml  ... including direct dependencies to b, c, e
     +- ...
        +- ...
```

Each project has its immediate ancestor as `<parent>`.

Note the omitting of the *transitive* dependencies:

- `a` at `GUI a`
- `a`, `d` at `GUI b`

See also:

- [POM Reference, Inheritance ff.](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Inheritance)
- [Maven: The Complete Reference , 3.6.2. Multi-module vs. Inheritance](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html#pom-relationships-sect-multi-vs-inherit)

Comment: I didn't knew that this was possible (with maven), which of course would make everything much cleaner. But how would the pom.xml look like, especially the main pom.xml. I guess that for the GUI x pom.xml I just need to specify the main one as its parent right? And do the same for the common projects.

Comment: @Westranger As mentioned the `main` POM should include all declarations inherited by all descendant projects (and the `<pluginManagement>` and `<dependencyManagement>` sections). You guessed wrong. ;) All `GUI x` projects should have `gui` as parent. Just `common` and `gui` have `main` as parent. I'm going to add some references to my answer.

Comment: Now I see that I misunderstood the meaning of parent here :-). What happens now if GUI b is not present when building GUI a. When building GUI a I dont want to check out GUI b, for me it looks like maven would now throw an error (just a guess) that GUI b is not present. In the end I only want the check out the GUI a and the necessary common projects and then build it, will this work with your solution ?

Comment: @Westranger This works if you just build `GUI a` in its directory since `GUI a` doesn't depend on `GUI b` in any way. The `common.project`s it depends on have to be built (with `mvn install`, at least) before at least once, of course. If any of the `GUI` projects is missing Maven will throw an error if  `gui` or `main` (automatically including its sub-modules)  are built in their respective directories.

Comment: I'll try to change all of our scripts appropriately and let you know of the result. Vielen lieben Dank :-)

Comment: tired it an got a small project working :-). Just one question: the main pom.xml at the very top is just to build all gui's at once right ? It doesn't have any other purpose right ?

Comment: @Westranger Great that it works! The `main` POM is both an aggregator (multi-module with `common` and `gui` as sub-modules) and a parent from which descendants inherit configuration. Such you can build _everything_ at once there, if desired, and it contains declarations common to _all_ descendant projects, `<dependencyManagement>` to use the same dependency version and `<pluginManagement>` to use the same plugin config in all descendants, for instance. If you want to build all GUIs at once you build in `gui`.